# Recursive snake pathfinding algorithm method

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion, path-finding

I am currently trying to implement a recursive snake path-finding algorithm. I tried to make something, but a problem came up that I find hard to fix. The problem is that my program is only searching for the path once and that for unknown reasons it is not going against the destination, but going one position ahead of it like that:

[image: Snake]

*The purple is the food and the green - snake. Aftar that it continues to the right and just goes out of the console.

*The "**Grid**" is a two dimensional boolean array which is as big as the console and a value is true if there is something like a part of the snake on the console.*

***Direction*** is an enumeration with Up, Down, Left, Right values. **Position** is a struct with two integers called X and Y.

***ScheduledDirections*** is a list with directions which will be used in the future for the snake's drawing on the console.

What I want to do is to add one available path to that list fast. I know about pathfinding algorithms like A*, but I find it too complex and hard to implement.

Source code:

```
private static void FindAvailablePath(Position currentPosition, Stack<Position> previousPositions, Direction currentDirection, Stack<Direction> previousDirections)
{
    // break if the snake's path search has ended or it went out of the console
    if (currentPosition.X < 0 || currentPosition.X >= Console.WindowWidth ||
        currentPosition.Y < 0 || currentPosition.Y >= Console.WindowHeight ||
        AIController.isReady)
    {
        return;
    }

    // break if there is something that is blocking the snake's path
    if (Snake.Grid[currentPosition.X, currentPosition.Y])
    {
        return;
    }

    // break if the snake has reached its destination
    if (currentPosition.Equals(AIController.Destination))
    {
        if (AIController.scheduledDirections == null || AIController.scheduledDirections.Count > previousDirections.Count + 1)
        {
            AIController.scheduledDirections = previousDirections.ToList();
            AIController.scheduledDirections.Add(currentDirection);
        }
        return;
    }

    // Break if previously visited
    if (previousPositions.Contains(currentPosition))
    {
        return;
    }


    // if the current path is available, adds it to the collection and checks for the next one
    if (!Snake.Grid[currentPosition.X, currentPosition.Y])
    {
        AIController.scheduledDirections.Add(currentDirection);

        previousPositions.Push(currentPosition);
        previousDirections.Push(currentDirection);

        if (AIController.Destination.X > currentPosition.X && !Snake.Grid[currentPosition.X + 1, currentPosition.Y])
        {
            FindAvailablePath(new Position(currentPosition.X + 1, currentPosition.Y), previousPositions, Direction.Right, previousDirections); // right
        }
        else if (AIController.Destination.Y < currentPosition.Y && !Snake.Grid[currentPosition.X, currentPosition.Y - 1])
        {
            FindAvailablePath(new Position(currentPosition.X, currentPosition.Y - 1), previousPositions, Direction.Up, previousDirections);    // up
        }
        else if (AIController.Destination.X < currentPosition.X && !Snake.Grid[currentPosition.X - 1, currentPosition.Y])
        {
            FindAvailablePath(new Position(currentPosition.X - 1, currentPosition.Y), previousPositions, Direction.Left, previousDirections);  // left
        }
        else if (AIController.Destination.Y > currentPosition.Y + 1 && !Snake.Grid[currentPosition.X, currentPosition.Y + 1])
        {
            FindAvailablePath(new Position(currentPosition.X, currentPosition.Y + 1), previousPositions, Direction.Down, previousDirections);  // down
        }

        previousPositions.Pop();
        previousDirections.Pop();
    }
}
```

Thanks! If anyone has any better suggestions I would love to hear them!

Comment: Didn't you ask this question already? I feel like I've seen it before.

Comment: I have asked a similar one yesterday.

Comment: You definitely don't need path-finding algorithms here like A* or dijkstra. You got the correct idea. Just check if a move which gets the snake closer to the destination can be done and then do it. And it can be done without recursion.

Comment: I would check an off-by-one error somewhere.  I don't see one in your posted code, but it might be worth it to take a look.

Comment: If you need to save your path, saving coordinates of snake's head is sufficient. No need to save direction since it can be found from two adjacent moves.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to find a path for a snake in a labyrinth.

Let's assume that it has infinite length. Then, the task is to find a path in a graph from initial position of snake to final

Doing it with dfs is a bad idea because it has O(N!) complexity. The dfs simply iterates through all path' in lexicographical order. In many cases it can be improved by heuristics like going to the closest to the destination point, however it is in any case time-consuming for this task.

On the other side, bfs works with O(N).

There is a code in c++, which implements the recursive algorithm and the bfs. c# and c++ have similar syntax.

```
    //<Just a code template>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<cstring>
#include<math.h>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<set>
#include<map>
#include<utility>
#include<time.h>
#include<queue>
#include<limits.h>
#include<bitset>
#include<deque>
using namespace std;
typedef vector<int>::iterator vit;
typedef string::iterator sit;
typedef vector<int>::reverse_iterator rvit;
typedef long long ll;
typedef long double ld;
//</Just a code template>

const int N=100;
bool Grid[N][N];

//Emulating your classes
struct TConsole
{
    int WindowWidth,WindowHeight;
    TConsole()
    {
        WindowWidth=WindowHeight=N;
    }
};
TConsole console;
struct Position
{
    int X,Y;
    bool Equals(Position other)
    {
        return X==other.X&&Y==other.Y;
    }
    Position(int _X=0, int _Y=0)
    {
        X=_X;
        Y=_Y;
    }
};

const int UP=0,DOWN=1,LEFT=2,RIGHT=3;
struct Direction 
{
    int cnt;
    Direction(int _cnt=0)
    {
        cnt=_cnt;
    }
    bool operator==(Direction other)
    {
        return cnt==other.cnt;
    }
    bool operator==(int other)
    {
        return cnt==other;
    }
};
Direction R=Direction(RIGHT);
Direction L=Direction(LEFT);
Direction U=Direction(UP);
Direction D=Direction(DOWN);
struct AI
{
    bool isReady;//What is it for?
    Position Destination;
    vector<Direction> scheduledDirections;
    AI()
    {
        isReady=false;
    }
};
AI AIController;

Direction prevdir[N][N];//Bfs stores for each cell destination with which it is entered
bool was[N][N];//if was[i][j] is 1, then the snake has visited position (i,j) in this branch of recursion in dfs case or just visited (bfs)
vector<Direction> path; // inversed path from start position to finish 

//function prototypes. To explain the compiler that their definition is somwhere below
bool dfs(Position pos, Direction dir);
void bfs(Position pos, Direction dir);

void calculate_schedules()
{
    //Restore the path from reversed and write it down
    reverse(path.begin(),path.end());
    for(vector<Direction>::iterator i=path.begin();i!=path.end();++i)
    {
        AIController.scheduledDirections.push_back(*i);
        printf("%d\n",*i);
    }
}
Position position_by_destination(Position initial, Direction d)//Returns a position to which snake comes, if it goes from position 'initial' in direction d
{
    if(d==U)
    {
        return Position(initial.X-1,initial.Y);
    }
    else if(d==D)
    {
        return Position(initial.X+1,initial.Y);
    }
    else if(d==R)
    {
        return Position(initial.X,initial.Y+1);
    }
    return Position(initial.X,initial.Y-1);
}
//Returns opposite to d direction
Direction get_inverse(Direction d)
{
    if(d==D)
        return U;
    else if(d==U)
        return D;
    else if(d==R)
        return L;
    return R;
}
//It starts from destination point and in each iteration 1)pushes the direction with which a current state was reached. 2)Goes to previous state
void bfs_path_restore(Position target,Position player)
{
    Position cpos=target;
    while(!(cpos.X==player.X&&cpos.Y==player.Y))
    {
        path.push_back(prevdir[cpos.X][cpos.Y]);
        cpos=position_by_destination(cpos,get_inverse(*(path.end()-1)));
    }
}
void FindAvailablePathBFS(Position currentPosition, Direction currentDirection)
{
    //The snake hasn't been anywhere
    memset(was,0,sizeof(was));
    path.clear();

    //Find path. 
    bfs(currentPosition,currentDirection);
    bfs_path_restore(AIController.Destination,currentPosition);

    printf("By BFS:\n");
    calculate_schedules();
}
void FindAvailablePathDFS(Position currentPosition, Direction currentDirection)
{
    //The snake doesn't know anything about the path, and hasn't visited anything but the starting point
    memset(was,0,sizeof(was));
    was[currentPosition.X][currentPosition.Y]=1;
    path.clear();

    //Find path. 
    dfs(currentPosition,currentDirection);

    printf("By DFS:\n");
    calculate_schedules();
}
int mabs(int x)// Abs function. The standard one tends to return double in some cases
{
    return x<0?-x:x;
}

//Positions' evaluation and comparsion function for their sorting based on it
int appraise_position(Position p)
{
    return mabs(p.X-AIController.Destination.X)+mabs(p.Y-AIController.Destination.Y);
}
bool heuristic_smaller(Position f, Position s)
{
    return appraise_position(f)<appraise_position(s);
}

//Returns direction of a snake when it goes from 'from' to 'to'.
Direction get_dir(Position from, Position to)
{
    if(to.X>from.X)
        return D;
    if(to.X<from.X)
        return U;
    if(to.Y>from.Y)
        return R;
    if(to.Y<from.Y)
        return L;
}

//Position pos is not in the console
bool out_of_bounds(Position pos)
{
    return pos.X<0||pos.Y<0||pos.X>console.WindowWidth||pos.Y>console.WindowHeight;
}
bool dfs(Position pos, Direction dir)//It returns true if managed to find position to the target with a state of was created by recursion
{

    if(out_of_bounds(pos))
        return false;

    //An obstacle
    if(Grid[pos.X][pos.Y])
        return false;

    //Got it
    if (pos.Equals(AIController.Destination))
        return true;

    //v contains all possible positions for the next step.
    vector<Position> v;

    v.push_back(Position(pos.X+1,pos.Y));
    v.push_back(Position(pos.X-1,pos.Y));
    v.push_back(Position(pos.X,pos.Y+1));
    v.push_back(Position(pos.X,pos.Y-1));

    //Evaluate them and process according to a result
    sort(v.begin(),v.end(),heuristic_smaller);
    for(vector<Position>::iterator i=v.begin();i!=v.end();++i)
    {
        //The snake was there in this branch
        if(was[i->X][i->Y])
            continue;
        Direction cdir=get_dir(pos,*i);
        if(cdir==get_inverse(dir))//This prevents the snake from turning inside out
        {
            continue;
        }

        //Go to next position and tell child branches that the snake was there
        was[i->X][i->Y]=1;
        if(dfs(*i,cdir))
        {
            path.push_back(cdir);
            return true;
        }
        //Return from position
        was[i->X][i->Y]=0;
    }
    return false;
}

//Processes a cell, finds closest ones to it and ads them to queue of procession. 
void bfs(Position pos, Direction dir)
{
    //Pathfinding starts from initial snake position
    queue<Position> qp;
    queue<Direction> qd;
    qp.push(pos);
    qd.push(dir);

    while(!qp.empty())
    {
        //Get current cell
        Position curpos=qp.front();
        Direction curdir=qd.front();

        //BFS processes cells in order of increasing distance from the first. Hence, if destination cell is found, it cannot be reached with less steps
        if(curpos.Equals(AIController.Destination))
        {
            qp=queue<Position>();
            qd=queue<Direction>();
            return;
        }

        //Find all neighbours
        vector<Position> v;

        v.push_back(Position(curpos.X+1,curpos.Y));
        v.push_back(Position(curpos.X-1,curpos.Y));
        v.push_back(Position(curpos.X,curpos.Y+1));
        v.push_back(Position(curpos.X,curpos.Y-1));

        for(vector<Position>::iterator i=v.begin();i!=v.end();++i)
        {
            //Check if a neighbour is acceptable
            if(out_of_bounds(*i))
                continue;

            if(was[i->X][i->Y])
                continue;

            if(Grid[i->X][i->Y])
                continue;

            Direction cdir=get_dir(curpos,*i);

            if(cdir==get_inverse(curdir))
                continue;

            //State that the way to the neighbour cell is found. Write destination with which the snake goes there to the corresponding prevdir. Add the cell to the queue
            was[i->X][i->Y]=1;
            prevdir[i->X][i->Y]=cdir;
            qp.push(*i);
            qd.push(cdir);
        }
        qp.pop();
        qd.pop();
    }
}

int main()
{
    freopen("test.in","r",stdin);
    freopen("test.out","w",stdout);

    int n,m;
    scanf("%d%d",&n,&m);
    char a[N][N];
    Position player,target;
    for(int i=0;i<N;++i)//Never do like this
    {
        for(int j=0;j<N;++j)
        {
            Grid[i][j]=1;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<n;++i)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<m;++j)
        {
            scanf("%c",&a[i][j]);
            if(a[i][j]=='\n')
            {
                --j;
                continue;
            }
            if(a[i][j]=='@')
                player=Position(i,j);
            else if(a[i][j]=='x')
                target=Position(i,j);
            if(a[i][j]!='*')
                Grid[i][j]=0;   
        }
    }
    AIController.Destination=target;
    FindAvailablePathDFS(player,D);
    FindAvailablePathBFS(player,D);
    return 0;
}
```

Note, that it is made in assumption that a path exists. This source gets a level map from test.in file, where @ means initial position of the snake, x - destination point and * - an obstacle The first two numbers should be width and height of the field.
Example of field:

```
7 7
.......
.......
..***.*
..*@*.*
..*...*
..*****
......x
```

---

Let's return to finite snake. Finite snake can visit the same place X twice, if its tail is already not there.

There are two cases:

a)The snake could move towards destination during the first visit of X. Then there is no point in not doing it.

b)The snake couldn't do it. Then, to move towards destination point it had to go back relative to head velocity.  Then the snake should try find the longest way to its tail  (to turn around and start from X) and, if it is impossible, to its head (To turn around in a part of a grid that is accessible), which is [NP-hard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem)

It's quite late. I probably missed something/